# FindInstance won't compute this simple expression

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, findinstance

[image]

I want to find instances where this standard **3x3** symmetric matrix has only positive eigenvalues.

So I run `FindInstance[Eigenvalues[R] > 0 ,  {a, b, c, f, g, h}, Integers]`

And it gets stuck in a never-ending computation *(the brackets turn bold and my computer's fan gets noisy)*. You'd think finding at least one matrix that fits this very general requirement would be easy.

For example, if I do the same on a simpler matrix:

[image]

It finds an instance instantly.

Note that what I want to do is actually have an additional requirement that the determinant must be 3: `FindInstance[ Eigenvalues[R] > 0 && Det[R] == 3,  {a, b, c, f, g, h}, Integers]`

And that also gets stuck in nonstop computation, of course. If I remove the Eigenvalue requirement I instantly get an answer though.

**Edit:** Changing the domain to Reals doesn't help either.

Comment: Have you seen this?: https://ericthewry.github.io/pdfs/imies.pdf

Answer (score 9):

A slick way is to compute the Cholesky decomposition of the starting matrix, and then impose conditions on the diagonal of the resulting upper triangular matrix:

```
Diagonal[CholeskyDecomposition[{{a, f, g}, {f, b, h}, {g, h, c}}]]^2 /.
Conjugate -> Identity
   {a, b - f^2/a, c - g^2/a - (-((f g)/a) + h)^2/(b - f^2/a)}

Reduce[Thread[% > 0], {a, b, c, f, g, h}]
   a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && -Sqrt[a b] < f < Sqrt[a b] &&
   -Sqrt[a c] < g < Sqrt[a c] &&
   (f g)/a - Sqrt[(a^2 b c - a c f^2 - a b g^2 + f^2 g^2)/a^2] < h <
   (f g)/a + Sqrt[(a^2 b c - a c f^2 - a b g^2 + f^2 g^2)/a^2]

(* find 10 instances *)
FindInstance[%, {a, b, c, f, g, h}, Integers, 10]
   {{a -> 89, b -> 48, c -> 49, f -> 9, g -> 21, h -> 21},
    {a -> 134, b -> 59, c -> 5, f -> -37, g -> 20, h -> -6},
    {a -> 530, b -> 8, c -> 72, f -> 16, g -> -176, h -> -7},
    {a -> 532, b -> 49, c -> 10, f -> -153, g -> 23, h -> -5},
    {a -> 638, b -> 89, c -> 11, f -> -209, g -> -44, h -> 9},
    {a -> 642, b -> 38, c -> 78, f -> -57, g -> -162, h -> 14},
    {a -> 663, b -> 89, c -> 28, f -> -220, g -> -83, h -> 15},
    {a -> 769, b -> 62, c -> 24, f -> -145, g -> -73, h -> 34},
    {a -> 816, b -> 55, c -> 12, f -> -193, g -> -15, h -> -4},
    {a -> 898, b -> 49, c -> 93, f -> -125, g -> -191, h -> -9}}
```

I'll leave you to figure out how to impose your extra condition of the determinant to be equal to $3$.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion):

```
{{a, f, g}, {f, b, h}, {g, h, c}}
FindInstance[{a, a b - f^2, a b c - c f^2 - b g^2 + 2 f g h - a h^2} > 0 // Thread, Variables[%], Integers, 5]
%% /. % // Map[Eigenvalues] // N
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `FindInstance`you could try `RandomInteger` and a loop:

```
m = {{a, f, g}, {f, b, h}, {g, h, c}};
While[par = {a, b, c, f, g, h} = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 6]; ! 
   And @@ Thread[Eigenvalues[m] > 0]];
Eigenvalues[mnum]
(mnum = m /. Thread[{a, b, c, f, g, h} -> par]) // MatrixForm
```

This gives e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit II**

Since `NMinimize` only return one solution,so we can change the restrictions to get another solutions.

```
n = 6;
A = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> Subscript[a, ##] &[i, 
      j], {i_, j_} /; i < j -> Subscript[a, ##] &[j, i]}, {n, n}] // 
   Normal;
variables = Variables[A];
ineqs = Thread[
   RandomReal[{0, 10}] < 
    Table[Det@Part[A, Range[i], Range[i]], {i, n}] < 
    RandomReal[{20, 30}]];
result = NMaximize[{0, ineqs, 
   AllTrue[variables, Element[#, PositiveIntegers] &]}, variables, 
  Method -> Automatic]
matrix = A /. Last[result]
matrix // Eigenvalues // N
PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[matrix]
```

> `{{6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3}}`

> `{{7, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}}`

etc.

**Edit I: The case when $4\leq n\leq 6$**

`NMinimize` is a powerfull way to find instance. `FindInstance` take long time and can't find a non trivial instance.

```
n = 5;
A = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> Subscript[a, ##] &[i, 
      j], {i_, j_} /; i < j -> Subscript[a, ##] &[j, i]}, {n, n}] // 
   Normal;
variables = Variables[A];
lower = RandomReal[1];
upper = RandomReal[20];
result = NMinimize[{0, 
   Thread[Table[Det@Part[A, Range[i], Range[i]], {i, n}] > 0], 
   lower < Sum[Det@Part[A, Range[i], Range[i]], {i, n}] < upper, 
   AllTrue[variables, Element[#, PositiveIntegers] &]}, variables, 
  Method -> Automatic]
matrix = A /. Last[result]
matrix // Eigenvalues // N
PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[matrix]
```

> `{{3, 1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2,  2}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 3}}`

> `{{2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2,  1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2}}`

**Original**

Another version inspire by @AccidentalFourierTransform

Apart from `FindInstance`, `NMaximize` is another way to find solution.

```
A = {{a, f, g}, {f, b, h}, {g, h, c}};
variables = Variables[A];
ineqs = Thread[Table[Det@Part[A, Range[i], Range[i]], {i, 1, 3}] > 0];
FindInstance[ineqs, variables, Integers, 2]
NMinimize[{0, ineqs, 
  AllTrue[variables, Element[#, PositiveIntegers] &]}, variables, 
 Method -> Automatic]
```

> `{{a -> 107, b -> 66, c -> 1, f -> 2, g -> -9, h -> -1}, {a -> 108,  b -> 1, c -> 1, f -> 9, g -> 2, h -> 0}}`

> `{0., {a -> 941, b -> 189, c -> 1, f -> 13, g -> 3, h -> 1}}`